# My Array isn't being filled the way I want it to, how would I fix this?

Tags: java

Apologies, I know this is a rather simple question but I am new to coding.

Here's the code I am using.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] intArrayCapital, intArrayLower;

        intArrayCapital = new int[26];
        intArrayLower = new int[26];

        char letter;
        int index;
        int ii;
        int jj;
        int kk;

        for(ii= 0; ii != 26; ii++) {       
            for(jj = 65; jj != 91; jj++) {               
                intArrayCapital[ii] = jj;     
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArrayCapital));
    }
}
```

Long story short, I want to fill in intArrayCapital with the numbers 65 to 90 which corresponds to the ASCII values of the capital latin letters. I want to do a similar one with the lowercase equivalent with another For loop with integers 97 to 122. I would use the first FOR loop as the index and have another FOR loop using kk. But I need to make sure the first array works properly.

This is the result when I system print it:

```
[90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90]
```

which isn't what I want. Could anyone please explain to me what I'm overlooking? and how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `intArrayCapital[ii] = jj;` should be `intArrayCapital[ii] = 'A' + ii;` and remove internal loop over jj

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thank you very much. I didn't realise that Java automatically converts the character into it's ASCII when assigned as an Integer so that meant the second loop was redundant. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be greatly simplified as you are currently using nested loops in a situation where they are unnecessary.

Typically a nested loop is used for iterating over 2 dimensional data, such as a matrix.  Your data is one dimensional as it is simply an array, not an array of arrays (e.g. `int [][]`).

Below is the simplified code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] intArrayCapital = new int[26];
    int [] intArrayLower = new int[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {               
        intArrayCapital[i] = 'A' + i;
        intArrayLower[i] = 'a' + i;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArrayCapital));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArrayLower));
}
```

This utilizes `'a'` and `'A'` to get the ASCII equivalent values (it is technically not using ASCII but that is out of scope of this question) instead of hard coding them, and adds the loop variable of `0` to `26` to fill both the upper and lower arrays at the same time.

Additionally, loop variables are typically named something like `i` or `j`, not `ii` or `jj` so I renamed them as in my opinion it is easier to read.

**Output:**

```
[65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to @llya Bursov. he figured it first

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] intArrayCapital, intArrayLower;
intArrayCapital = new int[26];
intArrayLower = new int[26];
char letter;
int index;
int ii;
int jj;
int kk;

for(ii= 0; ii != 26; ii++) {
    intArrayCapital[ii] = 'A' + ii;
}


System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArrayCapital));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here , although alternative approach is good but I am adding my answer so as OP can figure out the reason for the code not producing correct result.

The issue is with the nested loops. The inner loop results in putting the last value of jj that is 90 in each index. You can do the dry run and figure it out yourself. 
Replacing with single loop resolves the issue. Below are the 3 basic options you could use.

Option 1

```
for(ii= 0, jj =65; ii != 26; ii++, jj++) {         
    intArrayCapital[ii] = jj;
}
```

Option 2

```
for(ii= 0, jj =65; ii != 26; ii++) {         
    intArrayCapital[ii] = jj+ii;
}
```

Option 3

```
for(ii= 0; ii != 26; ii++) {         
    intArrayCapital[ii] = 'A' + jj;
}
```

Now point to note here is that code should be easy to read and maintain for future. Hence option 3 as suggested by everyone is the best of all 3.

Comment: The downside of the first two options however, is how you would need something like `jj + 32 + ii` though if you want to also fill `intArrayLower` with values at the same time, and it gets kind of confusing when a lot of numbers are hard coded that way.

Comment: @Nexevis Yes Agreed totally with you on that